# Unable to ping between router and routed port on L3 switch. Why?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, layer3

I've got an old Cisco 2811 connected to an old Cisco 4948 L3 Switch. I'm trying to teach myself a little more about L3 Switch implementation. All I'm trying to do at this point is get the router and the switch to pass data back and forth to one another via connected routes. I've not set up any VLAN interfaces on my switch at this point.

Anyway, here's what I've done so far on the L3 switch:
- configured g1/1 with `no switchport` command to make port a routed port
- configured g1/1 with `ip address 10.1.5.1 255.255.255.252` command
- configured g/1/1 with `no shutdown` command
- enabled ip routing with the `ip routing` command

One my router I've done the following:
- configured f0/1 with `ip address 10.1.5.2 255.255.255.252` command
- configured f0/1 with `no shutdown` command

On my L3 switch, the `show ip route` command shows a single connected route to 10.1.5.0. My router likewise show a connected route to 10.1.5.0. Both interfaces are in an up/up state. I erase startup config on both of these devices before attempting this to start from a fresh config, so no ACLs/port-security to speak of either.

What am I doing wrong here? Both the book I am using and the [online resource](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html) I've viewed seem to make this a fairly simple process, but I can't seem to get it to work. My pings always fail.

---

SWITCH CONFIG ABBREVIATED:

```
L3SW#show run

version 15.0
!
!
hostname Switch
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$srhK$ATA3JLvpsMlmDOR3MRLla.
!
username Andrew secret 5 $1$M8q1$R7mCw0srOjlMkZ2Fnf/Oh.
!
ip subnet-zero
!
!
power redundancy-mode redundant
!

vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 no switchport
 ip address 10.1.5.1 255.255.255.252
!
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
```

```
show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/30 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.1.5.0 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet1/1
```

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
Vlan10                 10.1.10.1       YES manual down                  down
FastEthernet1          unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
GigabitEthernet1/1     10.1.5.1        YES manual up                    up
```

```
show ip int g1/1
GigabitEthernet1/1 is up, line protocol is up
  Internet address is 10.1.5.1/30
  Broadcast address is 255.255.255.255
  Address determined by setup command
  MTU is 1500 bytes
  Helper address is not set
  Directed broadcast forwarding is disabled
  Outgoing access list is not set
  Inbound  access list is not set
  Proxy ARP is enabled
  Local Proxy ARP is disabled
  Security level is default
  Split horizon is enabled
  ICMP redirects are always sent
  ICMP unreachables are always sent
  ICMP mask replies are never sent
  IP fast switching is enabled
  IP Flow switching is disabled
  IP CEF switching is enabled
  IP CEF switching turbo vector
  IP Null turbo vector
  IP multicast fast switching is enabled
  IP multicast distributed fast switching is disabled
  IP route-cache flags are Fast, CEF
  Router Discovery is disabled
  IP output packet accounting is disabled
  IP access violation accounting is disabled
  TCP/IP header compression is disabled
  RTP/IP header compression is disabled
  Probe proxy name replies are disabled
  Policy routing is disabled
  Network address translation is disabled
  BGP Policy Mapping is disabled
  Input features: MCI Check
  WCCP Redirect outbound is disabled
  WCCP Redirect inbound is disabled
  WCCP Redirect exclude is disabled
```

```
show ip arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.1.5.1                -   001e.f7ad.0bff  ARPA   GigabitEthernet1/1
```

```
show int g1/1
GigabitEthernet1/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
  Hardware is Gigabit Ethernet Port, address is 001e.f7ad.0bff (bia 001e.f7ad.0bff)
  Internet address is 10.1.5.1/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, link type is auto, media type is 10/100/1000-TX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is off
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:15, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  L3 in Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
  L3 out Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
  IPv6 L3 in Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
  IPv6 L3 out Switched: ucast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes - mcast: 0 pkt, 0 bytes
     1053 packets input, 117356 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 221 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     265 packets output, 82637 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 1 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

---

ROUTER CONFIG

```
R3#show run
!
version 15.1
!
hostname Router
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$82m/$ZHiJirn9b4KrvdR.pPOak/
!
!
ip source-route
!
!
ip cef
!
username Andrew secret 5 $1$JNt6$cTb107naEHNeLx6YTQ2up.
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.1.5.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
```

```
show ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.1.5.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
L        10.1.5.2/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
```

```
FastEthernet0/1 is up, line protocol is up
  Internet address is 10.1.5.2/30
  Broadcast address is 255.255.255.255
  Address determined by setup command
  MTU is 1500 bytes
  Helper address is not set
  Directed broadcast forwarding is disabled
  Outgoing access list is not set
  Inbound  access list is not set
  Proxy ARP is enabled
  Local Proxy ARP is disabled
  Security level is default
  Split horizon is enabled
  ICMP redirects are always sent
  ICMP unreachables are always sent
  ICMP mask replies are never sent
  IP fast switching is enabled
  IP fast switching on the same interface is disabled
  IP Flow switching is disabled
  IP CEF switching is enabled
  IP CEF switching turbo vector
  IP multicast fast switching is enabled
  IP multicast distributed fast switching is disabled
  IP route-cache flags are Fast, CEF
  Router Discovery is disabled
  IP output packet accounting is disabled
  IP access violation accounting is disabled
  TCP/IP header compression is disabled
  RTP/IP header compression is disabled
  Policy routing is disabled
  Network address translation is disabled
  BGP Policy Mapping is disabled
  Input features: MCI Check
  WCCP Redirect outbound is disabled
  WCCP Redirect inbound is disabled
  WCCP Redirect exclude is disabled
```

```
show ip arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.1.5.1                0   Incomplete      ARPA
Internet  10.1.5.2                -   0025.845d.da09  ARPA   FastEthernet0/1
```

```
show int f0/1
FastEthernet0/1 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is MV96340 Ethernet, address is 0025.845d.da09 (bia 0025.845d.da09)
  Internet address is 10.1.5.2/30
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit/sec, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 100BaseTX/FX
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:08, output 00:00:04, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     361 packets input, 71268 bytes
     Received 361 broadcasts (0 IP multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     1001 packets output, 111588 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 6 interface resets
     225 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     7 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: Verify that both sides are 100M full-duplex

Comment: You should include the output from `show ip interfaces brief` and `show ip interface g1/1` on the switch and `show ip interface f0/0` on the router.

Comment: And `show ip arp` It might not be answering ping.

Comment: @RonMaupin Is there a way to save a txt file of a command out to tftp server? I'm kind of new at this.

Comment: DON'T set speed/duplex manually, generally. There are very few situations where this is required and otherwise it does much more harm than good. A duplex mismatch might be hard to spot.

Comment: @Zac67 It was just to experiment with things. I had it set to auto initially, but still the ping failed.

Comment: Simply entere the commands in your terminal application, then copy the lines and paste into your question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: @ahelton Please add the full (sanitized) configurations to your question. As it is, you're not providing enough information.

Comment: @RonMaupin Okay. It's just that the PC I have connected via the console cable to my Cisco device doesn't currently have an Internet connection. That's why I asked about the TFTP option. I'm typing this from a different location, so give me just a bit.

Comment: @Zac67. Got it. I didn't know if I needed to since I wiped all previous configuration on both devices and then reloaded both of them. I'll get that posted shortly. Thanks.

Comment: @RonMaupin Added config and show ip route info. If that's not everything you wanted let me know.

Comment: I really want the `show` commands I asked for. They will explain the current state of the interfaces.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry. Was getting you mixed with Zac. I'll post the show outputs from those as well.

Comment: @RonMaupin Okay. Added show output you requested. Also, I edited it original info to reflect the fact the router is using f0/1 and not f0/0.

Comment: `show interface gi 1/1` not `show ip interface gi 1/1`.  Same for Fa0/1

Comment: @RonMaupin Added.

Comment: Everything looks right. But I see “unknown protocol drops”.  Faulty cable?

Comment: I tried two different cables and the same cables work if the port is in L2 switchport mode, but I'm wondering whether or not when I enable IP Routing and put a interface into routed mode do I need to then use a crossover cable? I only start having issues when I place it in L3 routed mode. I thought the interface would be down if that's the case, but I'm kind of at a loss as to why it's not working. What's also weird is CDP works as each device picks up the other device. I don't know, maybe I'll try it on a different interface and see if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can tell is that the L3 switch is faulty. I was never able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set speed to 100 mbps on switch

Comment: As you can see from the output, the switch port is already at 100M.

Comment: Not important what it shows, try to set it manually